# Magento 2.3.2 Call to undefined function Magento\InventorySales\Model\IsProductSalableForRequestedQtyCondition\bccomp()

Tags: cart, magento2.3.2

When I am inserting product to the cart then below error is occured.

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function Magento\InventorySales\Model\IsProductSalableForRequestedQtyCondition\bccomp() in /home/public_html/vendor/magento/module-inventory-sales/Model/IsProductSalableForRequestedQtyCondition/IsSalableWithReservationsCondition.php:93 Stack trace: #0 /home/public_html/vendor/magento/module-inventory-sales/Model/IsProductSalableForRequestedQtyCondition/IsProductSalableForRequestedQtyConditionChain.php(222): Magento\InventorySales\Model\IsProductSalableForRequestedQtyCondition\IsSalableWithReservationsCondition->execute('B007D38J3M', 1, 1) #1 /home/public_html/vendor/magento/module-inventory-sales/Model/IsProductSalableForRequestedQtyCondition/IsProductSalableForRequestedQtyConditionChain.php(162): Magento\InventorySales\Model\IsProductSalableForRequestedQtyCondition\IsProductSalableForRequestedQtyConditionChain->processSufficientConditions('B007D38J3M', 1, 1) #2 /home/public_html/vendor/magento/module-inventory-s in /home/public_html/vendor/magento/module-inventory-sales/Model/IsProductSalableForRequestedQtyCondition/IsSalableWithReservationsCondition.php on line 93

How to solve this ?

Thanks in Advanced.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`bccomp()` function belongs to BCMath package; if it's undefined, then possible this library not installed or it's not enabled for your PHP version. Like for php7.2 need to install for ubuntu distribution:

```
sudo apt install php7.2-bcmath
```

Comment: thank it is worked for me